# How retour on line on cell of table pdflib

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

How I do do retour on line retour chariot on cell of table with pdflib 
I do that on cell

```
$tbl = $p->add_table_cell($tbl, $col, $row, $num."\r\n".$quote, $optlist);
```

but not do retour on line on cell of table

Comment: what exactly are you trying to say???

Comment: so i need this text for exampe MM MMM\r\nRRRRR must retour to line MMMM on line and the RRR the retour on line all that on cell of table

Comment: **you are mixing french and English language**... Please put your question in English.. Everyone does not know french...

Comment: so i need the retour to ligne on cell of table

Answer (score 0):

for a multiline table cell, you have to use a textflow cell. You find a simple sample in the PDFlib cookbook [starter_table.php](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/tables/starter-table/php-starter-table/):

```
    /* ----- Multi-line text with Textflow */
    $col++;
    $font = $p->load_font("Times-Roman", "unicode", "");
    if ($font == 0) {
        die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    $optlist = "charref fontname=Times-Roman encoding=unicode fontsize=8 ";

    $tf = $p->add_textflow($tf, $tf_text, $optlist);
    if ($tf == 0) {
        die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    $optlist = "margin=2 textflow=" . $tf;

    $tbl = $p->add_table_cell($tbl, $col, $row, "", $optlist);
    if ($tbl == 0) {
        die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }
```

You fill find a detailed introduction into PDFlib Table and textflow within PDFlib 9 Tutorial, chapter 8.3 and 8.2.